# Latitude E5470 Win 10 - Updates Taking Hours

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, ssd

Brand new laptops. Ship with Win7 but Win10 installed from included recovery disc (UEFI Boot, secure boot enabled). First big Windows 10 update takes about six hours on 'working on updates' phase during reboot.

I've had long update times after this also with further patches, including hours on 'Configuring Devices 100% after a reboot. It does eventually finish but it's a big inconvenience. Same updates have been fine on other machines.

This has happened with 4 E5470s.

Dell support wanted to install software from http://download.wsusoffline.net/ which I questioned and refused as I wasn't comfortable with it (if its a legit MS update, why can't we get it from MS?)

Has anyone else experienced this before? My inclination is that it is a driver causing the long update times. It's even the same with SSDs installed.

Comment: You do realize that, WSUS Offline downloads the files from Microsoft, right?  If you want to download hundreds of updates, you can do that, from the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/) although its worth pointing out your updates will still install slow even if you do it manually or use WSUS.

Comment: "Has anyone else experienced this before? My inclination is that it is a driver causing the long update times" - I only experienced long update times when there was indeed a problem with a device driver, i used my expertise to identify the driver, remove it, and install a updated driver, 9/10 times the problem was solved at that point.

Answer (score -1):

> > Dell support wanted to install software from http://download.wsusoffline.net/ which I questioned and refused as I wasn't comfortable with it (if its a legit MS update, why can't we get it from MS?)

If you visit the site, you'll see that it's not itself an update; it's a tool that will download most if not all available updates to e.g. a thumbdrive, and another tool that will install the downloaded updates to a target computer.

And having downloaded the updates once, you can use copies of the thumbdrive files to update as many PCs as you like at one time w/o having to clog your internet pipes.

I was able to use this to update a brand new Win7 laptop that would never update on its own, even if I left it on overnight.

SO again, it's not itself a legit MS update; it's a downloader for legit MS updates. Why can't we get it from MS?  They're the ones who can't get updates right in the first place. If they knew how to fix the problem more generally, they'd have done so and we wouldn't *need* a tool like this.

Comment: I suggest you remove the personal commentary from your answer.  The author's problem are not caused by a bad update so Microsoft's most current problem with a Windows 10 update (author is using Windows 7) is irrelevant.

Comment: I just realized the user is using Windows 10, although I still believe, the problem has nothing to do with the bad Windows 10 update that has already been fixed.

Comment: I'm not happy to use a third party tool for such a purpose on work computers (eg there are no guarantees as to its legitimacy, or what it may or may not break). Plus the laptop seems to find updates fine, just installing takes a long time- so what would this program be installing that Windows wouldnt normally?

Comment: >> what would this program be installing that Windows wouldnt normally?  In my case, updates.  Windows couldn't find any on its own.  If you don't want to trust a third party tool, that's your choice of course.